# PHP - Alternatives on passing variables to function using ...[array] in php 5.4

Tags: php

Is there an alternative function or way to pass variable inside function like
how php 5.6 does using "..."?

Ex:

```
function(...[$a, $b])
```

you can find this at example #7 on this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

I'm currently running a 5.4.4 (to be exact) environment and a bit scared of upgrading it.

--- sample code

```
$query->myFunction($var1, $var2, function($va1, $var2, $class){
      $class->anotherFunction($var1, $var2);
});
```

-- inside query builder

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2, $callback = null){
     $callback($var1, $var2, $this);
}
```

$callback - i want this callback function to be filled with variables automatically no matter how many i pass in it.. as what i said on #7 example.. that function will help me do this, and i'm searching for an alternative

Comment: Are you asking whether the way to pass function arguments is different in PHP 5.6 vs 5.4.4?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this kind of format

Ex: function($var1, $var2, $var3).. this is for my callback function

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the same, but you can get the arguments into an array with func_get_args and then process it from there.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this kind of format

Ex: function($var1, $var2, $var3).. this is for my callback function

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to receive the callback plus other arguments, you can use this:

```
function foo() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $callback = array_pop($args);
}
```

You now have `$args` with all function parameters before the final `$callback`. In order to call that callback, you need another related function:

```
call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
```

Study the documentation for those functions, they have a lot of rare and surprising "features" that you should be aware of.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood your query, I suggest you to use following functions -

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this kind of format

Ex: function($var1, $var2, $var3).. this is for my callback function

Comment: Can you write code in detail, that will help me to figure out what you want exactly ?

Comment: Do you mean that you can pass variables in any number, for example - $query->myFunction($var1, $var2, $var3, ....., $var4, function($va1, $var2, $var3, ....., $var4, $class){
      $class->anotherFunction($var1, $var2, $var3, ....., $var4);
});

Comment: Next answer may help you, please check. otherwise I'll try.